# How do I run a reoccurring function, in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'd like to run a function over and over, with a delay in between. How can I do this with Dart?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can use the `Timer` class to schedule one-shot and repeating functions.

### Repeating

Here is how you run a repeating function:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  const oneSec = Duration(seconds:1);
  Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => print('hi!'));
}
```

The Timer takes two arguments, a duration and a function to run. The duration must be an instance of `Duration`. The callback must take a single parameter, the timer itself.

### Canceling a repeating timer

Use `timer.cancel()` to cancel a repeating timer. This is one reason why timer is passed to the callback run from a repeating timer.

---

### One-shot after a delay

To schedule a one-shot function after a delay (execute once, some time in the future):

```dart
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  const twentyMillis = Duration(milliseconds:20);
  Timer(twentyMillis, () => print('hi!'));
}
```

Notice the callback for a one-shot timer does not take a parameter.

---

### One-shot as soon as possible

You can also request that a function is run as soon as possible, at least one event-loop tick in the future.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  Timer.run(() => print('hi!'));
}
```

---

### In HTML

Timers even work in HTML. In fact, `window.setTimeout` was removed, so Timer is the only way to run a function in the future.

Comment: If you are wondering, as I was, how to make a timer that does not depend on a compile time constant, the API docs for the timer has the following solution:  const ms = const Duration(milliseconds: 1); var duration = ms * variableMS; return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout); where variableMS is some int set other than as a compile time constant.

Comment: No constructor 'Timer.repeating' declared in class 'Timer'.  
dart editor intellisense shows Timer.periodic, I think they changed name

Comment: in another post you talk about using repeating futures, which one is the 'best' ?

Comment: Don't forget to call timer.cancel()   in dispose() method

Answer (score 34):

5 Sec Timer Example

```
bool isStopped = false; //global

sec5Timer() {
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
    if (isStopped) {
      timer.cancel();
    }
    print("Dekhi 5 sec por por kisu hy ni :/");
  });
}
```

Call from any function

```
sec5Timer();
```

Stop from any function

```
isStopped = true;
```

To dispose you can use this code or technique.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(widget.refreshRate, 
      (Timer timer) => _updateDisplayTime(inheritedWidget));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: like the bangla printing *Dekhi 5 sec por por kisu hoy ni :/* :D

Answer (score 25):

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/Stream/Stream.periodic.html

```
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription periodicSub;

void main() {
  periodicSub = new Stream.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), (v) => v)
      .take(10)
      .listen((count) => print('tick $count'));
}
```

or if the counter isn't required just

```
import 'dart:async';

StreamSubscription periodicSub;

void main() {
  periodicSub = new Stream.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500))
      .take(10)
      .listen((_) => print('tick'));
}
```

Comment: How can we use an "infinite" periodic function with a "cancel" action. take(10) only generate un recurring function with 10 call

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand the question. Please elaborate.

Comment: In my case, I need to have an "infinite" periodic function. This periodic function run indefinitely until it's stop by an "event" (Click on a button or exiting the page by exemple). In your case the take(10) argument allows only to run the function 10 times and can not be stop before (by example if we need to stop after 3 calls).

Comment: Search for rxdart. You can also use a StreamController to fully control a stream.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use Future.delayed and await to delay execution:

```
Future<Null> delay(int milliseconds) {
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));
}


main() async {
  await delay(500);
  print('Delayed 500 milliseconds');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was about running a function over and over (repeatedly).

Comment: You could put it inside `while(true)`

Comment: while(true) would eventually block the main thread and application would not be able to respond to user gesture events

Comment: I upvoted this because it made me realize this allows me to periodically execute some code and then do another delay. This ensures the "timer" doesn't keep executing while work is still being done (in case of heavy work that may or may not take more time than the scheduled delay).

Comment: Like so: https://gist.github.com/sfmskywalker/24e9e30b38d0bf8a8c453e7b38051514

Answer (score 4):

[alternative](https://dartpad.dev/b8354a85370a53984f39acfd5f1a3e19);

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer interval(Duration duration, func) {
  Timer function() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(duration, function);

    func(timer);

    return timer;
  }

  return new Timer(duration, function);
}

void main() {
  int i = 0;

  interval(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    print(i++);

    if (i > 5) timer.cancel();
  });
}
```

Comment: Isn't it making recursive timer ?

Comment: What's the point of returning the `Timer` from within `function`? The return value is never used, so it just seems to make the code harder to read?

Answer (score 3):

Opposite to Timer.periodic and Stream.periodic posting my favorite way to handle such a tasks. The advantages:

- the first cycle run instantly
- the callback can work longer than
  interval without any reentrance headache

```
Completer<bool> periodic(Duration interval, Function(int cycle) callback) {
  final done = Completer<bool>();
      () async {
    var cycle = 0;
    while (!done.isCompleted) {
      try {
        await callback(cycle);
      } catch (e, s) {
        log("$e", stackTrace: s);
      }
      cycle++;
      await done.future
          .timeout(interval)
          .onError((error, stackTrace) => null);
    }
  }();
  return done;
}

main() {
  final task = periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (cycle) async {
    /// do the periodic tasks here
  });

  /// main code here
  /// and when going to stop the above periodic call
  task.complete(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally identical code to JavaScript (setInterval, setTimeout, clearInterval and clearTimeout):

```
// ------------------------------
// Import:

import 'dart:async';

// ------------------------------
// Definitions:

void clearTimeout(Timer timer) {
  try {
    timer.cancel();
  } catch (e) {}
}

Timer setTimeout(VoidCallback fn, int millis) {
  Timer timer;
  if (millis > 0)
    timer = new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: millis), fn);
  else
    fn();
  return timer;
}

void clearInterval(Timer timer) {
  try {
    timer.cancel();
  } catch (e) {}
}

Timer setInterval(VoidCallback fn, int millis) {
  Timer timer;
  if (millis > 0)
    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: millis), (timer) {
      fn();
    });
  else
    fn(); // If millis input is too low, only run function once and stop
  return timer;
}

// ---------------------------------
// Example:

int myValue = 0;

Timer counter = setInterval((){ myValue++; }, 50);
setTimeout((){
    clearInterval(counter);
}, 5000);
```