# How to fetch data (method call) every five seconds in Flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter

In JavaScript, I could constantly fetch data without an explicit request from the user by calling a function `fetchData()` every five seconds using `setInterval(function() { fetchData() }, 5000);` and this is an incredibly useful tool for me. Is there a similar equivalent in Flutter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a reoccurring function, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart)

Comment: For flutter you can try with Stream and Stream Builder. I think this post will help you a lot. https://dev.to/nitishk72/understanding-streams-in-flutter-dart-2pb8

Comment: An answer below has provided [this link](https://dev.to/nitishk72/understanding-streams-in-flutter-dart-2pb8); I am preserving it here in case it is deleted.

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved by something like this.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  const fiveSeconds = const Duration(seconds: 5);
  // _fetchData() is your function to fetch data
  Timer.periodic(fiveSeconds, (Timer t) => _fetchData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer() and Timer.periodic() work the same way. They take duration as a parameter and an optional callback function.

```
 Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  // these lines would be executed every 5s.
});
```