# flutter run function every x amount of seconds

Tags: dart, flutter

inside my flutter app I want to check my api every 10 seconds. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart) to run a function every x amount of time and did the following:

```
class _MainPage extends State<MainPage> {
  int starter = 0;

  void checkForNewSharedLists(){
    // do request here
    setState((){
      // change state according to result of request
    });

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => checkForNewSharedLists());
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the requests pile up: after restarting the app on the first "round" there are two request to the api, the second round it's four requests, the third it's eight and so on...

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You can use like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549244/how-to-execute-a-method-in-a-certain-time-in-flutter/75875791#75875791:~:text=You%20can%20use,print(result)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B

Comment: How can i do same thing if app is in background?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

`build()` can and usually will be called more than once and every time a new `Timer.periodic` is created.

You need to move that code out of `build()` like

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer? timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => checkForNewSharedLists());
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Even better would be to move out such code from widgets entirely in an API layer or similar and use a `StreamBuilder` to have the view updated in case of updated data.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I will try the suggestion with the StreamBuilder, too. One question though: the questionmark in the dispose method is it a typo?

Comment: That was intentional, but not absolutely necessary. It's just to avoid an exception in case the timer was not yet set or set to null by some other code. It's the null-save navigation operator.

Comment: @acincognito did you try with StreamBuilder? if so please put some hints on it. thanks

Comment: How can i do same thing if app is in background?

Comment: @amit.flutter not sure what you mean. It's in the background. You just need *some* place to initiate it. It depends what you want to do what the best place is. If you don't want it inside a component, you can initiate it in `main()` before you run the app, but then you might not be able to do what you want when a timer event happens.

Answer (score 13):

Use [Cron](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) lib which will be run periodically, but there is a difference between Timer and Cron,

**Timer:** It's running a task on given specific time intervals whether it is seconds, minutes, or hours.

**Cron:** It's used for more complex time intervals, eg: if a task needs to be run on a specific time of an hour. let's see the diagram

[image]

The above diagram has an asterisk that represents a number that appears in a specific position.

```
import 'package:cron/cron.dart';

main() {
  var cron = new Cron();
  cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('*/3 * * * *'), () async {
    print('every three minutes');
  });
  cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('8-11 * * * *'), () async {
    print('between every 8 and 11 minutes');
  });
}
```

The above examples are taken from the repository which pretty well explains that the first **'*'** represents minutes, similar for the hour and so on as shown in the diagram.

Another example of the **hour** would be `Schedule.parse(* 1,2,3,4 * * *)`, This schedule will run every minute every day during the hours of 1 AM, 2 AM, 3 AM, and 4 AM.

for more reference
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: How can i do same thing if app is in background?

Answer (score 0):

Timer works fine, but you can also use Stream to execute a function periodicly:

```
final Stream _myStream =
    Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: x), (int count) {
       // Do something and return something here
});
```

see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/Stream.periodic.html

I was looking for code to run a function every n amount of seconds for x seconds in total. Also I added functionality to cancel the timer if the periodic Function returns a success before the total timer elapsed. So here is how to solve that:

```
bool success = false;
bool done = false;
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: n), () {
     done = true; 
     print("Timeout");
});
await Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: x)).takeWhile((_) => !done).forEach((_) async 
{
     success = await FunctionYouWantToExecutePeriodicly();
     done = success; // only if you want to finish the function earlier
});
```

Comment: will it work if app in background ?

Comment: Stream uses Timer under the hood actually.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS ANSWER FOR LONG PERIODS**

if you want to do specific job in long intervals without using any library or Timer :

you can use shared preferences to store the last time the job done :

`prefs.setString("last_time",TimeDate.now().toString());`

and for each access to the homepage you can compare the value stored "last_time" with the current time minus the interval (let's say 1 day) :

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();
DateTime time_ago = today.subtract(Duration(days:1));
String? last_time = prefs.getString("last_time");

if (last_time != null) {
    DateTime LC = DateTime.parse(last_time);
    if (LC.isBefore(time_ago)) { 
        //do job 
        prefs.setString("last_time",DateTime.now().toString());
    }
}
```