# How to rebuild the state after pushing a new screen

Tags: flutter, state-management

When i push a new screen onTap with Navigator and pass a new class constructor, how can I have that new screen updates every time `_playerTimer` updates without having to click again

Since the state of my new class only updates onTap, please help!

The build method of FullScreenDialog is called once since its only being  built when onTap is pressed

```dart
InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              return Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => FullScreenDialog(
                        _playerTimer,
                  ));
            },
            child: VideoPlayer(
                        _controller,)
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **setState** to rebuild the UI. 
ex:

```
setState((){
  _playerTimer = _playerTimer + 1;
});
```

that's about all the help I can give without seeing the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a new class (in your code would be the ***FullScreenDialog***) by passing an attribute, you're only saying to your code that a new class will be initialized by using the argument you provided.

If you want your *FullScreenDialog* class to always be updated when ***_playerTimer*** changes, you must observe this attribute inside this class by using **setState()**, which is a build-in function for **StatefulWidgets** that makes apps' UI update every time the observable attribute changes.

**Example**:

```
setState( () {
  _playerTimer = getUpdatedTimer();
});
```

Supposing that inside *getUpdatedTimer()* method you will manage the logic for updating this variable, calling a service or so. 
If you want this variable to be updated without interacting with interface, you probably will need a timer, too. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569602/flutter-run-function-every-x-amount-of-seconds) question to more details about it.

If you're starting with Flutter development, I suggest you to read this article ([Adding interactivity to your Flutter app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)) about state management
 and 
[setState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) documentation.

Hope that helps.