# Flutter - system event to detect start of new day?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app where I am displaying a list of tasks for the current day.

As the app can be running permanently,  I want a way of detecting when a new day starts (i.e. midnight) so that I can refresh the view to show the new day's tasks.

Is there a system event I can hook into when a new day commences?  Or do I have to roll my own time based checking notifier?

My project is being developed for both web and Android targets.

Comment: Did you see this ? See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549244/how-to-execute-a-method-in-a-certain-time-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datetime_loop](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_loop) that provide builder that return the datetime every seconds, minutes, hours or days, based on TimeUnit

```
DateTimeLoopBuilder(
  timeUnit: TimeUnit.days,
  builder: (context, dateTime, child) {
    return Text('$dateTime');
  }
)
```