# The getter 'Timer' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter

I was following [this stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569602/flutter-run-function-every-x-amount-of-seconds) to implement a timer operations at a one-second interval and is getting the captioned error. What do I have to do?

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () async {
      Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (Timer t) => print(t));
    }
  );
```

Error:

```
lib/main.dart:182:48: Error: 'Timer' isn't a type.                      
      Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (Timer t) => print(t));   
                                           ^^^^^                    
lib/main.dart:182:11: Error: The getter 'Timer' isn't defined for the class '_UploadPageState'.
 - '_UploadPageState' is from 'package:decg_main/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Timer'.
          Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (Timer t) => print(t));
```

Comment: can you share `_UploadPageState` too?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here: https://developermemos.com/posts/create-repeating-timer-flutter

1. Have to `import 'dart:async';`
2. Have to add `Timer timer =` prior to the `Timer.periodic()` function.