# How to call any method or page after every 1 second?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Whenever my home page was reloaded my data was updated but I want to reflect data instantly.
That's why I need a method that can refresh my page or method after every 1 second(flutter).
pls, help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter run function every x amount of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569602/flutter-run-function-every-x-amount-of-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Timer.periodic` to run a method every `Duration` you specify and using `StatefulWidget`n you can run it in `initState` like this:

```
  @override
      void initState() {
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
          print("this will execute every second");
        });
    
        super.initState();
      }
```

change the `print` with your method.

Answer (score 0):

This work's for me :smile:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 2200), 
 
(timer) {
   
 'Your Method'
     
 debugPrint('Timer 1 sec ${timer.tick.toString()}');
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in Your init state call the Timer like this

```
 @override
      void initState() {
        new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => YourMethod());//api call 
    
        super.initState();
      }
```

this will update your full screen