# Retrieve data from database every x minute for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Right now i want to retrieve a data from the database everytime the user open the app. I can put it inside the initstate. However that will work only if the user launch the app. Is there a way if i want to retrieve that database every x minute or everytime user open the app without launching it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a reoccurring function, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart)