# How to notify a user when JSON of a webpage changes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to know if there's a way I could get a JSON from a website online, and get to know when the JSON is updated, for example let's say its updated once in every 48 hours, so when the JSON gets updated I can notify the user of a change in the webpage.

An app version of something like https://visualping.io/ does basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such a task by following these steps:

- Fetch data from a `RestAPI` using `http get` method.
- Store the data locally
- Run the same method (which sends the http request to fetch data) at regular intervals of time (48 hours, in your case). [How do I run a reoccurring function, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart)
- Make use of state management approaches such as the `provider package` to listen to the changes in the locally stored data
- Update the user whenever the provider offers a changed value

I hope it was of any help.

Comment: Will the reoccurring function (Timer widget) work in the background when the app is shut?