# How to update text automatically instead of a button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want it so the function _getCurrentLocation() would be called repeatably and automatically so I wouldn't have to press the button to update the text. I don't really need the button, but I don't know how to do it differently.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("GPS"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            if (_currentPosition != null)
              for(var i=0; i<751;i++)
                if((mas[i][0]<=_currentPosition.latitude) && (mas[i][1]<=_currentPosition.longitude) && (mas2[i][0]>=_currentPosition.latitude) && (mas2[i][1]>=_currentPosition.longitude))
                  Text(
                      "LAT: ${_currentPosition.latitude}, LNG: ${_currentPosition.longitude},${mas3[i]}"),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("koordinātes"),
              onPressed: () {           
                 _getCurrentLocation();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),



      ),
    );
  }

  _getCurrentLocation() {
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        var globals;

      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly when would you like this function to be fired?

Comment: Constantly non stop.

Comment: When it finishes the for cycle I want it to star again

Comment: did you want to print the current location on-screen regularly?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: Maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart