# Repeat a function every one minute in background with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background

I'm writing an app with flutter to communicate with a weather station. The smartphone/tablet have to send via usb a command every one minute, recieve data from the station, and then send this data in a Firebase database.

I know that a smartphone is not the best device for do this, but I'm using an old device and I don't care about battery health (maybe a raspberry could be a better solution).

I'm using [usb_serial package](https://pub.dev/packages/usb_serial) to communicate via usb and [cron package](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) for timing the events. And all works fine.

The problem is that the app have always to run in foreground. The first solution that i tried is using two apps: (1) one that keeps the screen on (2) and another that makes the screen black to reduce the energy consumpion. This is not the best solution.

I think that a better way is to use a [background execution](https://android.jlelse.eu/modern-background-execution-in-android-bfae13c61b6b). I made some attempts with [workmanager package](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/workmanager) but the minimum frequency is 15 min, with [android alarm manager package](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) but I'm not sure that wakes up also the network connection.

Anybody can suggest me witch is the best way to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946013/13892187

In Dart for setting a recurring function we use the `Timer` class

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't have a timing problem, I use Cron package that works fine. My problem is doing this as background operation.

Comment: I don't have experience with this, but i will redirect you to something known as "isolates" in the Dart language which run in the background. I suggest you to check them once.