# Flutter location - speed is not reducing to zero when vehicle is stopped

Tags: flutter, dart, gps, location

I am trying to track user's speed and other gps data using location package.
Whenever user click on start trip button I am calling this method.

```
Future<void> _listenLocation(store) async {
    print('listen 1');
    location.changeSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 20, interval: 5000);

    _locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.handleError((dynamic err) {
      setState(() {
        _error = err.code;
      });
      _locationSubscription.cancel();
    }).listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      print('listen 2');
      setState(() {
        print('listen 3');
        _error = null;

        _location = currentLocation;


        print('_location');
        print(_location.speed);
        print(currentLocation.speed);


      });
    });

  }
```

I am getting data in listen only when user is moving or coordinates are changing. How can I get data even when user is not moving ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get data even when user is not moving ?

Just query it. The callback is for situations where you want to know when the data *changed*. Since you need the data *now*, whether it changes or not, just get it:

```
_location = await location.getLocation();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
How will I know that user is not moving ? because when user is moving I am listening to data (need current speed) and when user is not moving I need to show speed as 0

Comment: I guess you need a timer? I don't know how you calculate speed, but you cannot calculate speed just from positions... it's always (position delta *per time unit*) for example km/h.

Comment: we can get current speed using location.speed.
location package - https://pub.dev/packages/location

`class LocationData {
  final double latitude; // Latitude, in degrees
  final double longitude; // Longitude, in degrees
  final double accuracy; // Estimated horizontal accuracy of this location, radial, in meters
  final double altitude; // In meters above the WGS 84 reference ellipsoid
  final double speed; // In meters/second
  final double speedAccuracy; // In meters/second, always 0 on iOS
  final double time; //timestamp of the LocationData
}`

Comment: I am using same but I am getting that only when user is moving. Once user stops not getting data inside .listen(), that is my main concern.

Comment: And I just showed you how you can get data any time you want. Now you just have to figure out a way to set a timer and get the data yourself if your old data is "too old".

Comment: Pretty good examples of doing something on a timer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package for getting the speed of any vehicle.

```
StreamSubscription<Position> _positionStream;

double _speed = 0.0;

@override
  void initState() {
    _positionStream =
        Geolocator.getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
            .listen((position) {
      _onSpeedChange(position == null ? 0.0 : (position.speed * 18) / 5); //Converting position speed from m/s to km/hr
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onSpeedChange(double newSpeed) {
    setState(() {
      _speed = newSpeed;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _positionStream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Then use the `_speed` value wherever you need.

Hope this helps you to solve your problem!

Comment: Why is it giving non zero speed even if the device is not moving?

Comment: @AbdullahShahid for the first few seconds it will track your current location. So during that time, the speed may be non-zero. But once it's get's your accurate location. It will be zero.