# Flutter I have issue at firebase Auth creating user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a strange issue with my Firebase Auth at creating users,
when the user successfully signs up with his email and password it automatically goes to the login page even my awesome dialog shows but when I clock ok I get an error

that's my function

```
      UserCredential credential = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

I found out why it goes to the login page after I clicked the signup button when I removed the change state user it worked for me! but I need to check when the user opens the app from the beginning if he has an account or not so how do I achieve that?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'where to go',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        translations: Messages(),
        home: const SplashScreen());
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Timer? timer;

  _SplashScreenState() {
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 6), () async {
      setState(() {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
          if (user != null && user.emailVerified) {
            Get.put(UserController());
            Get.off(() => const HomePage());
          } else {
            Get.off(() => const Login());
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you share the code where you are calling for the navigation?

Comment: @Rainysidewalks I configured where the issue i will edit my question please can you look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i can see, you forget to add `timer.cancel()` in  `@override dispose()` method .

so try the following

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Timer? timer;

  _SplashScreenState() {
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 6), () async {
      setState(() {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
          if (user != null && user.emailVerified) {
            Get.put(UserController());
            Get.off(() => const HomePage());
          } else {
            Get.off(() => const Register());
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel(); // <--cancel the timer 
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

because you must cancel the periodic timer and to do that you need to cancels it explicitly but here putting it in the `dispose()` will handle that.

also see [how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart)

EDIT(part):

tell me if i got you wrong .

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Timer? timer;

  _SplashScreenState() {
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 6), () async {
      setState(() {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
          if (user != null) {
            if(user.emailVerified){
              Get.put(UserController());
              Get.off(() => const HomePage());
            }else{
              showDialog(
              //show diglog
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Title'),//edit text as you want on the title
                  content: Text('Content'),//edit text as you want as content
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // add code to do something on OK press
                      },
                      child: Text('OK'),//edit text as you want on the button
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // add code to do something on Cancel press
                      },
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          
          } else {
            Get.off(() => const Register());
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel(); // <--cancel the timer 
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

by using  `AwesomeDialog()`

```
 class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
   Timer? timer;
 
   _SplashScreenState() {
     timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 6), () async {
       setState(() {
         FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
           if (user != null) {
             if(user.emailVerified){
               Get.put(UserController());
               Get.off(() => const HomePage());
             }else{                        
               AwesomeDialog(
                 context: context,
                 dialogType: DialogType.info, // dialog type.
                 animType: AnimType.SCALE, //pass the animation or  AnimType.rightSlide,
                 title: 'email is not verified',
                 desc: 'please verify you email!',
                 btnCancelOnPress: () {
                   //code logic on cancel press here
                 },
                 btnOkOnPress: () {
                   //code logic on ok press here
                 },
                           )..show();
           
           } }else {
             Get.off(() => const Register());
           }
         });
       });
     });
   }
 
   @override
   void dispose() {
     timer?.cancel(); // <--cancel the timer 
     super.dispose();
   }
 }
```

Comment: sorry I solved it by adding Register at my main but I need to keep it my login() its the problem at (user != null && user.emailVerified) condition still confused how to make it right

Comment: i did not get it so please explain what you mean by "confused"  .

Comment: I made a condition if the user is null or not verified go to the login page else go home when the user signs it becomes not null so It goes for login page automatic but I need to keep on the register screen to show awesome dialog message

Comment: i added two types of dialog see is that what you are asking about and if so then please edit your question to in a language that will address all the issue what you are looking  for ,so that it will be easy for other to access the material if they are looking for the same.